# RangeValidator Problem in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, validation

I was using RangeValidator to validate user input on client side for double values.

One of my user said that when he enters 5E-10, my range validator does not understand that number as a valid double.

What do you suggest me to do?

Thanks,
cas

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem with RangeValidator.

You'll need to use a `CustomValidator` instead, and manually verify the user's input is within the allowed range - including allowing scientific notation.